# Why doesn't this Applet show a thing?

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class IdrawApplet extends Applet  {  
Button myButton;
Panel pPanel;

  public void init() {
    myButton=new Button("Clear");
    pPanel = new Panel();
    pPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pPanel.add(myButton,BorderLayout.NORTH);
  }
}
```

Why dont't I see anything when I run it? Plus I get a strange Warning.

"The serializable class IdrawApplet does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long."

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you leave your panel? Don't you have to draw it or add it to a root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the panel to the applet itself using its add() method.

You can (almost safely) ignore the warning or just add this to the class's variables:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why don't I see anything when I run it?

You don't add the panel to the applet.

Since you are just learning applets, why don't you start by creating a Swing applet instead of an AWT applet. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Applets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) for a working example to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

You added the button to the panel, but you didn't add the panel to the applet:

```
add(pPanel);
```